# MVC3 jQuery Autocomplete - User must select option, ID of option sent to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**Background**

Currently in a project of mine I am using jQuery `autocomplete` for a few fields.

To provide context, the application records `Runs`. Each `Run` must have a `Route` associated with it. A `Route` meaning, where the user ran.

When the user types in a `Route`, a list of their `Routes` gets displayed by the `autocomplete` options, but the database requires the `RouteID` for validation.

To compensate for this, I stored the `RouteID` in a `HiddenFor` HtmlHelper. When the user selects the route from the `autocomplete`, the `HiddenFor` gets assigned.

**What my problem is**

If the user types in the full name of the `Route`, instead of selecting it from the `autocomplete` list or enters a `Route` that does not exist, the `HiddenFor` will not get assigned. When this happens, I have to find the `Route` by its name and validate that it exists on the server.

I would like to not have to create this work-around for every `autocomplete`.

**The bottom line**

Is there anyway to make the `autocomplete` act more like a `select list`? I want the user to have no choice but to select the text of one option from the `autocomplete` list, and have the value of the selected option is sent to the server.

If I have to stick to the `HiddenFor` method, is there at least a way to force the user to select an option from the `autocomplete` list?

---

*Below is the code I am currently using*

**Mark-up**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RouteID, "Route")
<input type="text" data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("../Route/GetRoutesByUser")" />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RouteID)
```

---

**jQuery**

```
  $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
    .each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                log(ui.item.id, ui.item.name);
            }
        });
    });
```

---

**Code**

```
public ActionResult GetRoutesByUser(string term)
{
    var routeList = db.Routes.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(term))
                    .Take(5)
                    .Select(r => new { id = r.RouteID, label = r.Name, name = "RouteID"});
    return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of fiddling around I came up with the following implementation:

The code below is a `HtmlHelper` called `@Html.AutocompleteWithHiddenFor`. The HtmlHelper will create an `input` HTML element with a `data-autocomplete-url` property based on the `controller` and `action` passed in.

If the `input` element needs a `value` then you can pass that in as well. A `HiddenFor` will be created for the `Model` property passed in and a `ValidationMessageFor` will be created for the `Model` as well.

Now all I have to do is use `@Html.AutocompleteWithHiddenFor`, and pass in whatever expression I need with the controller and action (and possibly the value) **to get the autocomplete functionality and have the ID pass to the server instead of the text**.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    function log(id, name) {
        var hidden = $('#' + name);
        hidden.attr("value", id);
    }

    $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
    .each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                log(ui.item.id, ui.item.name);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    this.value = '';
                } else {
                    log(ui.item.id, ui.item.name);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

**AutocompleteHelper class**

```
public static class AutocompleteHelper
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Given a Model's property, a controller, and a method that belongs to that controller, 
     /// this function will create an input html element with a data-autocomplete-url property
     /// with the method the autocomplete will need to call the method. A HiddenFor will be
     /// created for the Model's property passed in, so the HiddenFor will be validated 
     /// and the html input will not.
     /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteWithHiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string controllerName, string actionName, object value = null)
      {
          // Create the URL of the Autocomplete function
          string autocompleteUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName,
                                                       controllerName,
                                                       null,
                                                       html.RouteCollection,
                                                       html.ViewContext.RequestContext,                                                              
                                                       includeImplicitMvcValues: true);

           // Create the input[type='text'] html element, that does 
           // not need to be aware of the model
           String textbox = "<input type='text' data-autocomplete-url='" + autocompleteUrl + "'";

           // However, it might need to be have a value already populated
           if (value != null)
           {
               textbox += "value='" + value.ToString() + "'";
           }

           // close out the tag
           textbox += " />";

           // A validation message that will fire depending on any 
           // attributes placed on the property
           MvcHtmlString valid = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);

           // The HiddenFor that will bind to the ID needed rather than 
           // the text received from the Autocomplete
           MvcHtmlString hidden = html.HiddenFor(expression);

           string both = textbox + " " + hidden + " " + valid;
           return MvcHtmlString.Create(both);
     }
}
```

---

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RouteID, "Route")
@Html.AutocompleteWithHiddenFor(model => model.RouteID, "Route", "GetRoutesByUser")
```

Or if it needs a *value*

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Route, "Route")
@Html.AutocompleteWithHiddenFor(model => model.RouteID, "Route", "GetRoutesByUser", @Model.RouteName)
```

Comment: Remember to add: using System.Web.Mvc; and using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

Comment: Of course. It wouldn't build otherwise. I omitted them because the code was long enough as is. Visual Studio will let you know what libraries need to be imported as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `change` event for this, clearing the value of the `input` if an item was not selected:

```
$('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
    .each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                log(ui.item.id, ui.item.name);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) { 
                if (!ui.item) { 
                    this.value = '';
                } else {
                    // Populate your hidden input.
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/urEzm/

Comment: Thanks a lot for leading me to the change event. It definitely helped in terms of usability. After a lot of toying around I came up with my own implementation that a reusable HtmlHelper for this process.